# Check if the content of a QTextEdit is a valid font. - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently making a notepad in Qt and now I'm making the font section.
I want the user to input a font in a QTextEdit and when he presses enter the app checks if it is a valid font, otherwise it will show a MsgBox saying that it isn't and to enter a new one.
How do I make this?

Comment: Off topic: why make the user type in a font specification rather than simply using [`QFontDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html)?

Comment: please, see [Qt notepad example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html)

Comment: off topic: why are you two always the only one that answer me? Btw Imma check the notepad example

Comment: @G.M. I wanna make the user specify a font in a QTextEdit cause it looks more modern.

Comment: It's not modern. It damages your UX . Users should not memorize the font's name. but QFileDialog has a search area that helps users to type their fonts.

Comment: _off topic: why are you two always the only one that answer me?_ Maybe, these are the two guys around the world (and active in Stack Overflow) which have the hints at hand you're looking for. Btw. I'm not sure if 2 occurrences justify an estimation of "always". I remember that our math. prof preached as, concerning statistics, a sufficiently large sample is always important for a reasonable statistics evaluation. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem, I'm so stupid tho.
I used a Font ComboBox.